# Why is my code returning "ValueError: x and y must be the same size"?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("https://sites.google.com/site/yasinunlu/home/research/new1/auto_mpg_modified.csv")
df.drop(['name'], inplace=True, axis=1)
missing_col = ['cylinders', "origin", "horsepower"]
for i in missing_col:
    df.loc[df.loc[:,i].isnull(),i] = df.loc[:,i].mean()
df_clean = df.astype({"cylinders":int, 
                  "year": int,
                  "origin":int,
                  "mpg":float, 
                  "displacement":float, 
                  "horsepower":float, 
                  "weight":float, 
                  "acceleration":float})
response = df_clean[['mpg']]
features = df_clean.drop(["mpg"], axis = 1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
my_result_list = train_test_split(features, response, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
features_train = my_result_list[0]
features_test = my_result_list[1]
response_train = my_result_list[2]
response_test = my_result_list[3]

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
my_linear_regression = LinearRegression()
my_linear_regression.fit(features_train, response_train)
response_pred = my_linear_regression.predict(features_test)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize = (7,6))
plt.scatter(features_train, response_pred)
plt.ylabel("Prediction", size = 12)
plt.xlabel("Actual", size = 12)
plt.show()
```

Why does this code show the following error?

> ValueError: x and y must be the same size

x is features_train which is 80% of the dataframe df_clean.

Comment: hi, what is your intention with `plt.scatter(features_train, response_pred)`? Did you mean `plt.scatter(response_train, response_pred)` (note the first argument)?

Comment: Your features_train has 7 features for each y. Please try and consider how you would plot this on a 2-dimensional (or 3-dimensional) plot, and you will see there's a problem.

Comment: ...and please include the full traceback of the error (starting from the word "Traceback") in the possible future questions.

Comment: Yes, I did mean response_train

Comment: In that case, your `response_train` is 80% of your dataset target value, while `response_pred` (gotten from predicting off of `features_test`, or 20% of the dataset) is also, only 20% of the dataset long. Did you mean to plot `response_test` vs `response_pred` instead ?